# What is the format of azure "scopes"?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

In the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac) of the `az ad sp create-for-rbac` command there is a `--scopes` parameter. It is defined as:

> **--scopes**
>   Space-separated list of scopes the service principal's role assignment applies to. Defaults to the root of the current subscription.

There is also an example given:

```
--scopes /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup1}
```

However it is not clear what is the general format of the scopes. That is can to level be something else than resource groups? Can we drill down to individual resources withing a resource group? How?

How do I get the correct value for this parameter to be able to scope the account access to a particular individual resource? How do I specify the path?

Is it possible somehow to list children of an arbitrary scope?

Comment: To individual resource, just specify the `--scopes` with the resource id of the azure resource, in general, you can find that in your resource in the portal -> `Properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scopes are IDs of resources that you want to grant access to. They can be obtained with the help of the [`az resource list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-list) command. For example:

```sh
az resource list --location westus
```

The result will contain an `id` field, that will contain the scope you are looking for, such as:

```sh
"/subscriptions/0db1a886-c5b6-49fb-a7de-23f5cd6579d3/resourceGroups/hugo-blog/providers/microsoft.cdn/profiles/hugo-cdn"
```